# Do you always need to run separately the pom.xml of each projects in Maven before deploying to Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven

I have a main application called MainApp. This app contains a dashboard project and store project. Whenever I make change to either dashboard or store project, I had to run the maven clean install via IntelliJ for the project where I make the change. Then I go to my maven configuration for the MainApp pom.xml then run the pom.xml via clean install tomcat7:run -Pfront-end-build -U to deploy the project.

Is this the right way of doing it? I know this is a bit subjective,but I was thinking won't it be possible to just compile, build and run everything from MainApp? I noticed when I run the pom.xml in MainApp, it just gets the dependency wars ( store and dashboard ) from our Nexus repo (so I guess that war don't contain my latest changes).

```
MainApp
pom.xml
-----dashboard
-------pom.xml
-----store
-------pom.xml
```

MainApp pom.xml

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.pab</groupId>
    <artifactId>MainApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>    

    <modules>
        <module>store</module>
        <module>dashboard</module>
    </modules>   

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       dependency....    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webapps>
                        <webapp>
                            <contextPath>/store</contextPath>
                            <groupId>com.pab</groupId>
                            <artifactId>store</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                        </webapp>
                        <webapp>
                            <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                            <groupId>com.pab</groupId>
                            <artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <asWebapp>true</asWebapp>
                        </webapp>
                    </webapps>                        
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>   

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            <url>${release.repo.url}</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <url>${snapshot.repo.url}</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

dashboard pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>dashboard</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pab</groupId>
        <artifactId>MainApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <webpack.cmd>webpack</webpack.cmd>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>front-end-build</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>dashboard</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>                   
                    <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>                
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

store pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>store</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>   
    <name>store</name>   

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pab</groupId>
        <artifactId>MainApp</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../</relativePath>
    </parent>  

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>front-end-build</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <finalName>store</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING>false
                        </org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING>
                    </systemProperties>                  
                    <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>src/main/client</workingDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>npm</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>install</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>webpack</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>npm</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>run</argument>
                                    <argument>build</argument>
                                </arguments>
                                <environmentVariables>
                                    <NODE_ENV>
                                        production
                                    </NODE_ENV>
                                </environmentVariables>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now, after struggling with this for quite some time. I did some more testing.
I run mvn clean install -Pfront-end-build -U via git bash in the MainApp folder, essentially this executed the pom.xml in that folder which is the parent pom.xml of the inner modules. It successfully built the inner modules store and dashboard. However what I noticed is, when i execute this command in IntelliJ: clean install -Pfront-end-build -U tomcat7:run  . The inner modules are not being built. It seemed that the tomcat  plugin is trying to deploy the modules immediately thus it is trying to get the war files from the repository. This is where the problem lies now. For now, what I'm doing is i build the whole project (together with the inner modules) outside intelli J then go back to intelli J and run the tomcat maven plugin (tomcat7:run) so I'll have the option to debug through the code using intelli J.

Comment: The top level pom should be able to clean and compile the inner modules

Comment: @cricket_007 Hmmm..how do i do that? my top level pom has the <modules> element. My understanding is whatever pom xmls that are found under those moules, they also get executed, thus the inner modules gets built as well?

Comment: They should be, yes. Run a clean at the top folder... Do you see the output stages from the others?

Comment: I execute the MainApp pom.xml with clean install tomcat7:run -Pfront-end-build -U , the other two projects don't seem to be built because I tried putting in some changes in one of the project and I cant see the change reflected in the deployed web application

Answer (score 0):

Your main pom xml has store and dashboard defined as modules so if you `mvn clean install` at main pom xml it should build both the projects and your changes should be reflected in new war.

```
<modules>
    <module>store</module>
    <module>dashboard</module>
</modules>
```

If you are running tomcat in ide like eclipse then once you build your project then it should show synchronized or needs synchronized besides tomcat server. If later then right click on tomcat server and restart tomcat server and it should synchronize i.e. redeploy wars on tomcat server.

Comment: Just like what I said above... 
 
I execute the MainApp pom.xml with clean install tomcat7:run -Pfront-end-build -U , the other two projects don't seem to be built because I tried putting in some changes in one of the project and I cant see the change reflected in the deployed web application ...and im using Intelli J.

Comment: When you run the command do you see modules being rebuild or not on console?

Comment: The dependencies found in the main pom.xml is being downloaded. After that, the two modules (store and dashboards) war files are being downloaded as well from the local nexus repository. The inner modules in itself are not being built. And then maven goes to deploy the project to tomcat.

Comment: Can you add maven-install-plugin in pluginManagement and plugins and give it a shot?

Comment: added this one <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement> , still the inner modules are not getting built.

Comment: You have to add pluginManagement and plugins both. Like  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: i added both already,same result. I noticed when running the main app pom.xml, the target directory in the MainApp is deleted, but not the target directory of \MainApp\dashboard\target. When I run clean install in the dashboard project, i can see that \MainApp\dashboard\target directory is deleted.

Comment: I added some more new observations in the question above.